# Will deleting the hidden .git folder in the Xcode project folder reset Xcode source control back to pre-source control?

Tags: xcode, git

I enabled source control for my Xcode iOS project and I'd like to restore the project's state back to before I enabled source control. I can go into Xcode preferences and disable source control but I want to bring it back to the pre-source control state.

There is a hidden `.git` folder in the project's folder.

1. Is all of Xcode's source control for my project contained in this one folder?
2. Will deleting this folder reset Xcode source control back to pre-source control for this project?
3. Are there any possible unintended side effects of deleting this folder?

Comment: why don't you create a copy of your project folder and then check for yourself ? What's the issue?

Comment: @OMiShah because there may be unintended side effects that I wouldn't notice in this copy and paste experiment. And this copy and paste experiment doesn't answer any of my questions definitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm not sure that Xcode is relevant to your question, and my answer is independent of any tools other than Git.

> 1. Is all of Xcode's source control for my project contained in this one folder?

Yes, unless you deliberately moved something outside of the root folder.

> 2. Will deleting this folder reset Xcode source control back to pre-source control for this project?

**No. It will leave it in the state of your current working folder.**

(Question 3 is therefore irrelevant.)

As a trivial example consider:

1. You create a file, say, `testfile.txt` with contents, "line 1".
2. You initialize a Git repository. At this moment you have 1 untracked file, `testfile.txt`.
3. You create a second file, say `testfile2.txt` with contents "another file".
4. You stage the two files and create your first commit.
5. You modify both files by adding a second line.
6. You stage and commit the changes to both files to create a second commit.
7. You delete the Git repo. (By deleting the `.git` folder.)

After step 7 your two files are exactly how you left them, which is different from where you started in step 1.

**The best you can probably do is to checkout your very first commit, and this will be perhaps as close as possible as to where you started before you created the Git repo.** (This of course assumes you have actually created some commits!)

In my trivial example above it wouldn't be exactly where you started in step 1 because changes were made between the time when the repo was created and the first commit. Perhaps you can remember if you changed anything in that time period, but by checking out the starting commit you'll at least be closer to where you started, if not exactly where you started.

**Important Note:** If you had never created the Git repo in the first place you'd possibly be completely stuck with no simple way to go back to a previous state. (Unless some tool on your machine does automatic snapshot backups.) Fortunately you did create a Git Repo; this is exactly what Git is for and by checking out any previous commit you can get back to that state. Now that you know that you can't do what you thought, and that Git is actually helping you in your scenario, I'd consider not deleting the repo after all. Instead, consider creating a branch where you are now, perhaps:

```
# Make sure your current status is clean with `git status`.
# If you have pending files consider stashing or committing
# them before performing the steps below.

git branch swing-and-a-miss # save your current state to a named branch
git log --reverse # show the log in reverse order to see the first commit
git reset --hard <first-commit-id> # re-point your current branch
# e.g. if you're on main, you'll repoint main to that first commit

# now look to see if you're happy with this commit-
# If you're happy- then great, continue working from here.

# If you're not happy, then:
git reset --hard swing-and-a-miss
# You're back to where you were before you read this answer
```

Comment: This is a wonderful answer! So, to help me better understand Git, the git folder is rather independent of the project's source files, correct? All this folder does is give Xcode, in this case, the ability to remember versioning history. And so removing it just removes this history and the ability to revert, branch, etc. Is this how git works for all IDEs and projects? Is it always just a folder that is independent of the project like this?

Comment: "Is this how git works for all IDEs and projects? Is it always just a folder that is independent of the project like this?" Yes to both. Git tracks the files you tell it to track by adding (staging) files and creating commits. Once you have a commit, when you create/delete/modify those tracked files, Git shows you the differences, and you can create new commits at any time to save that new state. I recommend creating commits often while developing. (I may create 5-100 commits per day, and you can always squash and fixup commits later.) The IDEs interact with the file system, and Git notices.

Comment: Many IDEs (including Xcode) also present the ability to interact with Git as well. All they are doing is putting a UI around certain commands so you don't have to type them yourself. I used to prefer using a UI instead of typing Git commands myself, but the more I learned about Git the more I prefer the command line. Nowadays I almost exclusively use the command line for everything, except for viewing graphs and comparing commits.

Comment: And because you are so well versed in Git, I'm curious, do you include 3rd-party dependencies, like CocoaPods, in your repo?

Comment: @lurningtookoad typically you don't checkin (commit) the actual 3rd-party libraries (binaries), but you would checkin the configs that specify which version of the libraries to use. You can use the `.gitignore` file(s) to exclude any binaries from Git that can be built, or pulled in from a package manager.